# Validation of Laravel does not show me the errors in the view

Tags: laravel, validation

I have this in the controller...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'long_description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $product = new Product();
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== '_token') $product->$key = $value;
    }
    $product->save();

    return redirect('/admin/products');
}
```

And this in the view...

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{‌{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The form without the validation works perfect. But I do not understand why he does not show me the errors in the view when redirected.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using currently

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but iterating over `$errors->all()` and adding the properties is a bad idea and lets users set ANY property in your model (and potentially cause errors), even if you don't want them to edit it. Instead use `Product::create($request->all());` and set the `$fillable` property on the model to whitelist properties that can be set by the user.

Comment: I use Laravel version 5.7.

Comment: Thanks to the two, luckily it was solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this-

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'long_description' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (!$validator->fails()) {
        $product = new Product();
        foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
            if ($key !== '_token') $product->$key = $value;
        }
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/admin/products');
    } else {
        \Session::flash('errors', $validator->messages());

        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
}
```

I made two changes in your code-

1. Added validate method on $request instead of $this.
2. Added a check for failed validation and sent those errors through a session.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved. The problem was that I had the post route inside api.php. By moving it to web.php it works.